# Inserting a dynamic number of rows into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-queries

Is there a way to insert a dynamic number of rows from within sql server (.sql script) given the value of a look up, and setting one column for each insert? 
I want to attach a row with the foreign key of every row in a different table.

For instance:

```
table 1:
1 j k l m n 2-(fk)
2 j k l m n 3-(fk)
3 k u y k l 2-(fk)


table 2:
2 hi you
3 hey ho
```

Now say I wanted to add 2 rows to table 1, with the fk values from table 2 of 2 and 3.

So the final table would look like:

```
table 1:
1 j k l m n 2-(fk)
2 j k l m n 3-(fk)
3 k u y k l 2-(fk)
4 a a a a a 3-(fk)
5 a a a a a 2-(fk)
```

With a programming language, this would be easy. Psuedo: 
    For (rows in table 2) DO
        Insert into table 1 'a a a a a rows.id'

How could this be accomplished within sql server?

Edit:

For every row in table 2, get it's id, set it as the fk in a row for table 1, and insert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT [table 1]
SELECT 'a','a','a','a','a', fk 
FROM [table 2]
```

Comment: apologies, comment deleted. I didn't understand what you had written until I re-read.

Comment: does the FK stand for Foreign Key? if not what else?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, someone came along and showed me a way to do this...

```
insert into table_one  
select col1 = 'a',  
   col2 = 'b',  
   col3 = 'c',  
   col4fk,  
   col5 = 'k'  
from table2
```

It's only selecting col4fk from table 2, as long as it has the same name as the column in table 1.

Comment: That's practically the same query I posted ... name qualifying the columns in an insert ... select is meaningless, it uses column ordering, you can specify insert into table (a,b,c) if you want to ensure the ordering is right